# Use pipenv whenever possible in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

How could I force vscode to always find and prefer pipenv's virtual environment for python instead of the python's global settings?

When I create a `pipenv` environment on my workspace, it keeps using the global python version at /usr/bin/python (as defined in settings as `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"`) but I wonder how could I switch to something like `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Selenium-10eAXqZ4/bin/python` automatically when there is Pipenv environment detected.

Is this even possible? If this is how can I configure it?

*(I'm not talking about simply overriding the python.pythonPath with local `.vscode/settings.json` I need this to detect the path from `pipenv` automatically when it exists for the current project)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` to your environment and the `.venv` folder will be added to your project root. VSCode has zero problems picking up Python from there. (I find it also very convenient to have everything in one place and not spread around on the entire disk.)

Comment: Yes that would solve it, but I wonder how to do this with the default pipenv settings (when the environment is located under the ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/...) I prefer to have all of my venvs in a single directory

Comment: There isn't a specific way to tell the extension, "when you start, pick the pipenv environment without me doing anything". At minimum you will need to run `Python: Select Interpreter` to make the initial selection.